# Authentication frameworks used by IT industry players?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on

I am doing a systematic literature review on academic articles related to authentication and user-context and experience (UX), however, I would like to have an idea of which existing solutions and frameworks are employed by current solid companies in the IT market. Is there any industry standard for authentication, user-context, and identity?

So far I have identified a few solutions like "Microsoft Identity-Server" which supports OAuth and SSO.

Thanks in advance if you guys can share with me some existing and available frameworks.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two examples:
SAML 2.0 and
OCSP

You can look up EU legislation 910/2014 for the EU regulation "on electronic identification and trust services for electronic transactions in the internal market and repealing Directive" for an european framework.
https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=uriserv%3AOJ.L_.2014.257.01.0073.01.ENG